# JavaScript: Nullifying a variable that points to an object nullifies the variable not the object?

Tags: javascript, variables, javascript-objects

Essentially, I have a *heavily* nested object, so I create variables to access that object so i don't have to write the entire nested object in order to perform an operation.

The problem is that when I create a variable and manipulate it by setting it to null, the variable gets set to null, but the object it's referencing does not.

Conceptually I kind of understand what's going on, but if that's what's going on then I have been wrong about a basic property of javascript for roughly 4 years... which is fine, being wrong is how growth happens, but still.

```
var thing = { 
    content: { 
        area: { 
            row: { 
              column: {a: 'a', b:'b', c:'c'} 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 

var contentArea = thing.content.area;
var row = contentArea.row
var column = row.column;

column = null;
console.log(row.column);
// logs  {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}
console.log(column);
// logs null
row.column = null;
console.log(row.column);
// logs null.
```

#### Can anyone tell me why this happens and point me to a reference where I can read more about why it happens?

---

---

it's worth noting that if you try to set something rather than nullifying something, THAT change is persisted. kind of. rather than setting the above to null, try this:

```
column.a = 'purple';
console.log(row.column);
console.log(column);
//both log {a: "purple", b: "b", c: "c"}
```

however if you try to set the object to something else, it does not persist to the object:

```
column = 'purple'
console.log(row.column);
console.log(column);
// logs {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}
// 'purple
```

Comment: Because you are reassigning the variable ... not the object value. This is expected behavior. You break reference to object when you reassign the variable. No different than `var a=1, b=a, a=2; alert(b)// is still 1`

Comment: but why does column.a ="purple" work but not column = 'purple'?

Comment: because you are changing a property value in the object that `column` references ...not reassigning the whole variable `column`

Comment: so you're changing what the variable points to rather than what the variable it points to is.

Comment: mind.blown. if you put your comments as an answer, you'll get some rep ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: [Evaluation Strategy - Call by Sharing](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Evaluation_strategy#/Call_by_sharing)
And this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

What is essentially boils down to is this:

1. Setting a variable in Javascript points it to a new 'value' (primitive object). Thats why nullifying or setting `column` to 'purple' doesnt change the underlying object. It just points `column` to something else.
2. BUT, setting `column.a` does work, because column is pointing to the same object as your nested column, so setting a property on one will reflect on the other.

Comment: awwww yeah. that evaluation strategy thing is exactly what i was looking for.